# Want to update the getView method, when using a GridView

Tags: java, android

I'm using a baseadapter class for my calender in which it populates the calender with icons corresponding to the data in the database. However I want the code within the getView to update whenever a user clicks on the calender, therefore showing a new icon immediately. How do I do this without creating a new instance of the baseAdapter class?

Here is my baseAdapter class:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For update ListView and gridView you should call method adapter.notifyDataSetChanged.
It will refresh all visible items. And you should return new View in getView() method which depends of you wish.

Comment: What does .notifyDataSetChanged do? Does it run the getView method again? Because the code to show the 'icons' on the calender are stored in the getView() method I need to run it again somehow? Also I am already returning the view in getView() arnt I?

Comment: Yes you have a right. The notifyDataSetchanged() will recall method getView() for all visible items.